# 403 Forbidden and can't understand why Angular Django

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django & Angular, i'm building a project with authentication. The authentication seems to work well, but when i'm connected, i only got a 403 error on every request i do. Everything in the frontend seems to work but i can't access my views or viewsets.

My frontend code is as follows (players-list.component.ts):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.list().subscribe(response => {
      this.playerList = response.body;
    });
  }
```

Here is my players.service.ts :

```
export class PlayersService {
  constructor(private http: RestService) {}

  public list(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.list("players");
  }
}
```

Now my list method in rest.service.ts :

```
  public list<T>(endpoint: string, getParams: any = {}): Observable<any> {
    const inline: string = this.getInlineGetParams(getParams);
    return this.http.get<T>(`${RestService.API_ROOT}/${endpoint}/${inline}`, {
      headers: {
        ...RestService.DEFAULT_HEADERS
      },
      observe: "response"
    });
  }
```

Every console.log i do in this frontside code works.

My django views are as follows :

```
class PlayersViewSet(HasRoleMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print ('sdmlkfnqmfndn') #This doesn't print
        return super.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.all().order_by("number")
```

My print in my viewset doesn't print. So I guess the 403 error is raised before entering the viewset.

Here is my urls.py :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"players", PlayersViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^auth', AuthAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

And finally my settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "g9a^4)@v%(jc*u_xt*g_0#1^bj5(7^^=0yh#4z-77*dl5hbk-p"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False  # not DEBUG
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = os.getenv("SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN", None)
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False  # not DEBUG
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
# Application definition

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',

    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
    # greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
    # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'new_app',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my-app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my-app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    "http://localhost:4200",
    "http://localhost",
)
```

If you guys could help me, i would be so thankful, i've been trying to solve this for 2 days !

Thanks !

Edit : My django error is as follows :

```
 Forbidden (Permission denied): /players/
 [03/Mar/2020 14:49:59] "GET /players/ HTTP/1.1" 403 22
```

Comment: 403 means that you are not authenticated or you are not sending CSRF token. Could you share your error message?

Comment: You use the `HasRoleMixin` but I can't see the `allowed_roles` being set anywhere, you might need to set the `allowed_roles`?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?